# Lightbox realized, but some functions missing

Tags: jquery, css

if I click on a picture it gets large and if I click on that pictuere, the following picture is shown.
But there is no "X" to close and no arrows to go forwards or backwords as in the example
"https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples".
How do I get them?

Comment: Are you willing to post your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I completely deinstalled lightbox and started again. Now it is working.
I don't know what was my error before.
Thank you!